# NullPointerException Error while using AsyncTask in onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-asynctask, onactivityresult

I want to Select Image from gallery and crop it,then upload the image to server.If upload success,change view,if upload fail,them give a message;

I Use onActivityResult to manage this,and I use AsyncTask to make http post, dismiss the progressDialog,and save Image,Then i ran to this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo...
```

and it caused by

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

in my AsyncTask codes;

Here is my button to crop

```
avatarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }
    });
```

and onActivityResult code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode){
        case 1:              
            if (data != null) {    
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                crop(uri);
            }
        case 2:
             if (data != null) {
                    final Bitmap bitmap = data.getParcelableExtra("data");
                    new UploadAvatar(UserProfileActivity.this, bitmap).execute();
                }   
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Crop method

```
private void crop(Uri uri) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");

    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);

    intent.putExtra("outputX", 100);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 100);

    intent.putExtra("outputFormat", "PNG");
    intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
}
```

and AsyncTask class

```
class UploadAvatar extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Boolean> {
private Context context;
private String avatarString;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private ImageView avatarImage;
private Bitmap avatar;

public UploadAvatar(Context contextin,Bitmap bitmap){

    this.context = contextin;
    this.avatar = bitmap;
    View rootView = ((Activity)contextin).getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    this.avatarImage = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.setavatar);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("正在上传头像");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    progressDialog.show();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
    if(avatar == null){
        Log.d("222","Null");
    }
    //Here i Got error,that avatar is null;
    avatar.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,90,baos);
    byte[] b=baos.toByteArray();
    avatarString= new String(b);
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... param){
    //try upload Image to server
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result){
    ...//do some work
}
```

}

It totally confused me,because i got this Error when i click on a Image in gallery,trying to call Crop(),I didn't finish my crop,so the Bitmap data is obvious Null,it seems execute AsyncTask before i finish my crop.It's quite confusing,in the crop() method i start intent to crop like this:`startActivityForResult(intent, 2);`

But onActivityResult executed the codes before the Result is deliver back.

Please help, Thanks in advance.This really draw me crazy. :(

Update:
Here is some more NullPointerObject stack trace code:

```
at com.example.allen.bubbles001.Activity.UploadAvatar.onPreExecute(UserProfileActivity.java:229)
at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
at com.example.allen.bubbles001.Activity.UserProfileActivity.onActivityResult(UserProfileActivity.java:168)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3347)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3394)
```

The first entry point at

```
avatar.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,90,baos);
```

in UploadAvatar.onPreExcute

The fourth entry point at

```
new UploadAvatar(UserProfileActivity.this, bitmap).execute();
```

in onActivityResult

Comment: Can you share more of your stack trace leading up to the NullPointerException?  It'd be helpful if you could point out on what line the Exception was thrown.

Comment: @MichaelKrause Updated some more Stack trace codes

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the bitmap that is null. You seem to be pulling it out of the "data" Intent, which is probably not a good idea in the first place. Intents have a maximum size limit for extras, and if the Bitmap is large, you will easily go over the limit. Instead, I would recommend saving it to disk and putting the filename in the Intent as an extra so you can read it from the file instead.

Comment: That's not the solution.The question is onActivityResult excute the AsyncTask code first before Crop could produce any image.Ofcourse it's Null,but thank your for Advise

Comment: @Jschools is correct. In your case the problem is in case 2 of your `onActivityResult()`. The bitmap you are getting from `data.getParcelableExtras()` is null . Try using `(Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");`  and try inspecting your Intent's contents before you start your asynctask

Comment: Right: you can't assume that the device even supports the CROP intent: https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html